# How am I able to pass a variable over to a button click event?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I passed a variable from one page to another for a pop up menu. I want to be able to add the selected adviser to the favorites list. The issue is, when I pass the variable to one page, it only allows me to use it for that specific method. I am trying to get it passed to a Button Click event,(OkayButtonClicked), so it will be saved to the favorites list. I have tried two different attacks to this.

I have tried: 
Declaring the button, using FindByName from the xaml code x:Name property.
`Button okaybutton = FindByName("OkayButton") as Button;`

Then I tried two different ways of using this variable to pass the string.

One way was:

```
okaybutton += (sender2, e2) => OkayButtonClicked(sender2, e2, selectedAdvisor);
```

The second way was:

```
okaybutton += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   OkayButtonClicked(sender, e, selectedAdvisor); 
};
```

(selectedAdvisor is the variable that was passed from one page to the current one I am on, which is where the problem is occurring)

There is one error, each, that I get with these.

First One: 
"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type "Button" and "lambda expression"

Second One:
"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type "Button" and "anonymous expression"

(The Button click event that I am trying to get the variable passed to)

```
private void OkayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

    DisplayAlert("Attention", "You have successfully added Adviser to said List", "Okay"); 
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a basic C# scoping issue.  But it's hard to suggest a fix because your explanation of the problem is very unclear.  It sounds like you are passing a variable from page A to page B - how specifically are you doing this?  Using the constructor of Page B?  Or some other method?  And then on Page B you want to use this variable from within a button's clicked handler?

Comment: private void onFavoriteImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) { PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new FavoriteButtonPopupView(selectedAdvisor));    Then I have an argument on "Page B" that accepts this variable.

Comment: so, yes, you are passing the variable in the constructor of Page B.

Comment: Yes. I am passing the variable in the constructor of Page B. I just thought that maybe you would like to see the code just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you constructor for `FavoriteButtonPopupView` probably looks something like this

```
public FavoriteButtonPopupView(string selectedAdvisor)
{
  ...
}
```

the `selectedAdvisor` variable you pass is **locally scoped** - meaning it is only visible within the constructor, and other methods on that page can't access it.

What you need to do is create a **class level variable** that will be visible to all methods of the class.

```
private string SelectedAdvisor;

public FavoriteButtonPopupView(string selectedAdvisor)
{
  // store the parameter in a class level variable so other methods can access it
  SelectedAdvisor = selectedAdvisor;

  ...
}

private void OkayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    // do something with SelectedAdvisor here

    PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

    DisplayAlert("Attention", "You have successfully added Adviser to said List", "Okay"); 
}
```

note - this is basic C# and has nothing specific to do with Xamarin

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue. I guess I was just overthinking it. I need to step back more. You really helped me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **okayButton +=** you need to use **okayButton.Click +=** event.

Your code should be like

okaybutton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 .....
};

You can only use **+=** with an **event** or **delegate** in c#. You can't use += operator with a button instance

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I will go ahead and give this a try sometime in the future.